# Invalid argument: logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[16,8] labels_size=[16,4]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, transfer-learning

I’m doing a CNN project for classification of Corn disease images(4 classes) It uses VGG16 as its base model. I have created and saved the model. Now is it possible to use that model as a base for another transfer learning task to classify cotton leaf disease images( 4 classes) with retaining the knowledge gained from corn disease images along with cotton leaf disease images? If so how should I modify the corn disease model. Should I need to make the output layer neurons as 8( 4 for cotton, 4 for corn disease) ?
Here is my code for Cotton plant CNN using corn plant model as base. I tried it by removing last two layers (output and dense layer) then added new dense layer followed by output layer with 8 neurons but when I train the model I get error that logits and labels must be broadcastable.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
savedmodel = load_model('corn.h5')
train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
test_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
val_gen = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=preprocess_input)
traindata = train_gen.flow_from_directory('/Users/saibalaji/Desktop/data/train/',target_size=(224,224),batch_size=16)

class_labels = []
for class_label,class_mode in traindata.class_indices.items():
    print(class_label)
    class_labels.append(class_label)
nmodel = tf.keras.Sequential()

for layer in savedmodel.layers[0:-1]:
    print(layer)
    nmodel.add(layer)
for layer in nmodel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

nmodel.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=15,activation='relu',name='dense_3'))
nmodel.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8,name='cf',activation='softmax'))
nmodel.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
nmodel.fit(traindata,epochs=5)
```

Here is my saved model summary for corn leaf disease images(4 classes) here I used feature extractor transfer learning by reatining conv2d and maxpool layers of vgg16.
[image]

How should I need to modify the model for cotton leaf disease by retaining the knowledge gained from corn plant by using transfer learning.

And here is my modified model for Cotton plant disease.
[image]

But i get this error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The knowledge of the model trained on corn images is resident in the model weights. Just load the model, then train it on the cotton images.

Comment: Ok but which layers  should be frozen?

Comment: none. The model is starting with the weights from the first training session so that information is there. Your second training session will fine tune the model for your new dataset

Comment: Ok but when I train the model on new dataset which has 4 classes similar to corn dataset. So I added 8 output neurons(4 for corn and 4 for new dataset classes) instead of 4 but I can't fit the model I get an error "logits and labels must be broadcastable" I use ImageDataGenerator() in keras to load the images of new dataset(4 classes).